# Black Screen with MSAA on Android with Vulkan

Tags: android, vulkan

I have a problem with MSAA setup on Android. On any desktop machine tested (Intel, NVIDIA) I get a correct resolve framebuffer and renderpass (I currently have an empty renderpass where I only clear the back color) and the screen renders simply grey (desired) but on android the screen is black.

I do not get any validation errors. The code just "works" but it does not seem right to me.

Here is my Renderpass code:

```
VkSampleCountFlagBits sampleCount = GetMaxUsableSampleCount();

VkAttachmentDescription colorResolveAttachment = {};
colorResolveAttachment.format = mSwapchainImageFormat;
colorResolveAttachment.samples = sampleCount;
colorResolveAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
colorResolveAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
colorResolveAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
colorResolveAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
colorResolveAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
colorResolveAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentDescription colorAttachment = {};
colorAttachment.format = mSwapchainImageFormat;
colorAttachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
colorAttachment.loadOp = (mSamples != 0) ? VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE : VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
colorAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
colorAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
colorAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
colorAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
colorAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;

VkAttachmentDescription depthResolveAttachment = {};
depthResolveAttachment.format = mDepthImageFormat;
depthResolveAttachment.samples = sampleCount;
depthResolveAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
depthResolveAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
depthResolveAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
depthResolveAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
depthResolveAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
depthResolveAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentDescription depthAttachment = {};
depthAttachment.format = mDepthImageFormat;
depthAttachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
depthAttachment.loadOp = (mSamples != 0) ? VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE : VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
depthAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
depthAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
depthAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
depthAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
depthAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference colorAttachmentRef = {};
colorAttachmentRef.attachment = 0;
colorAttachmentRef.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference depthAttachmentRef = {};
depthAttachmentRef.attachment = (mSamples != 0) ? 2 : 1;
depthAttachmentRef.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference colorAttachmentResolveRef = {};
colorAttachmentResolveRef.attachment = 1;
colorAttachmentResolveRef.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkSubpassDescription subpass = {};
subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
subpass.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachmentRef;
subpass.pDepthStencilAttachment = &depthAttachmentRef;
if(mSamples != 0)
{
    subpass.pResolveAttachments = &colorAttachmentResolveRef;
}

std::vector<VkSubpassDependency> dependencies;

if(mSamples != 0)
{
    std::array<VkSubpassDependency, 2> dependency;

    dependency[0].srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    dependency[0].dstSubpass = 0;
    dependency[0].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT;
    dependency[0].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    dependency[0].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
    dependency[0].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    dependency[0].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;

    dependency[1].srcSubpass = 0;
    dependency[1].dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    dependency[1].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    dependency[1].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT;
    dependency[1].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    dependency[1].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;
    dependency[1].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;

    dependencies.push_back(dependency[0]);
    dependencies.push_back(dependency[1]);
}
else
{
    VkSubpassDependency dependency = {};
    dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
    dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    dependency.srcAccessMask = 0;
    dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;

    dependencies.push_back(dependency);
}

std::vector<VkAttachmentDescription> attachments;

if(mSamples != 0)
{
    attachments.push_back(colorResolveAttachment);
    attachments.push_back(colorAttachment);
    attachments.push_back(depthResolveAttachment);
    attachments.push_back(depthAttachment);
}
else
{
    attachments.push_back(colorAttachment);
    attachments.push_back(depthAttachment);
}

VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo = {};
renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
renderPassInfo.attachmentCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(attachments.size());
renderPassInfo.pAttachments = attachments.data();
renderPassInfo.subpassCount = 1;
renderPassInfo.pSubpasses = &subpass;
renderPassInfo.dependencyCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(dependencies.size());
renderPassInfo.pDependencies = dependencies.data();

if(vkCreateRenderPass(mDevice, &renderPassInfo, nullptr, &mRenderPass) != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    Console::FatalError("Failed to create render pass!");
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Here is my Freambuffer code:

```
if(!CreateMultiSampleTargets())
    return false;

mSwapchainFramebuffers.resize(mSwapchainImageViews.size());

for(size_t i = 0u; i < mSwapchainImageViews.size(); i++)
{
    std::vector<VkImageView> attachments;

    if(mSamples != 0)
    {
        attachments.push_back(mMultiSampleColorImageView);
        attachments.push_back(mSwapchainImageViews[i]);
        attachments.push_back(mMultiSampleDepthImageView);
        attachments.push_back(mDepthImageView);
    }
    else
    {
        attachments.push_back(mSwapchainImageViews[i]);
        attachments.push_back(mDepthImageView);
    }

    VkFramebufferCreateInfo framebufferInfo = {};
    framebufferInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
    framebufferInfo.renderPass = mRenderPass;
    framebufferInfo.attachmentCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(attachments.size());
    framebufferInfo.pAttachments = attachments.data();
    framebufferInfo.width = mSwapchainExtent.width;
    framebufferInfo.height = mSwapchainExtent.height;
    framebufferInfo.layers = 1;

    if(vkCreateFramebuffer(mDevice, &framebufferInfo, nullptr, &mSwapchainFramebuffers[i]) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        Console::FatalError("Failed to create framebuffer!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I should mention that my code is heavily based on this: https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/multisampling/multisampling.cpp

Comment: Maybe first try without the depth attachments. ;; why do you have two different sets of dependencies? ;; (While you have it there,) does it work for the case of `mSamples == 0`?

Comment: It works without issues with MSAA disabled (mSamples == 0). With MSAA enabled it does not work and android. All other tested platforms do not have issues. The MSAA support where added afterwards. That explains the crappy design of the code. Also see this comment https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/commit/a12ff647369a583f9065fd05ef3bfc6afff67d4e. I will test without the depth attachment.

Comment: Sorry for the very long delay. I had no time actually testing it without the depth attachments but I upgraded my phone (Oneplus 3) to android 8 yesterday which gave me a newer driver. And it works now! I guess it was a bug in the driver as occlusion query results where also wrong sometimes. Now it gives the same results on every platform! Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade my Oneplus 3 to android 8 to get a newer driver version where this issue does not occur. I guess this was a driver bug.